# Link domain name with dynamic ip

Tags: ip, names, domain-name, dyndns, noip

I recently bought a domain name from Names.co.uk.

My home internet has Dynamic IP and I want to link this ip with my domain name.

**Is there a way?**

PS: I have a No-Ip.org account as well.. 
will this help to set everything together?

Thank you all for any help or advice

Kind regards 
Yiannis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can I Use My Own Domain Name with No-IP?**

> Upgrading to [No-IP Plus Managed DNS](http://www.noip.com/services/managed_dns/plus_dynamic_dns.html) lets you use your own domain
>   name(s) with No-IP.
>
> To add your own domain visit our Managed DNS services page.  You’ll be
>   prompted to add the domain name(s) that you want added to our system.
>
> Pricing for this service can be found on our [pricing page](http://www.noip.com/services/service_pricing.html).